# What type of hinge: 180 degree, but only 135 degree motion

Tags: doors, cabinets, hinges

I have an odd section of wall that I'm putting cabinet doors on.
In case the picture doesn't load, it's 2 framed walls stopping about 18 inches short on both walls before they would touch. So the doors are at a 45° angle.

I'm looking for a couple of hinges, that would allow the door to open pretty wide, about 135° from closed, but the mount needs another 45 to get to the post.

I've attached a quick drawing of what I mean.

I would think a concealed hinge that opens to 180° would work, but then there would be another 45° of travel that the door couldn't make, because it would already be closed. Which would, I suppose, block the soft close option on a hinge. Is there a hinge that fits that?

[image]

Comment: You should be able to find near-180 deg hinges.  just mount them on a 45 degree wedge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take 2"x2" wood, and cut a 45 Dgr in it.

Mount it on the wall.

Now mount the 180 hinge on it,.

[image: hinge]

It will allow for soft close.